# How to return string to client after setting header

Tags: javascript, php

I have a download button on my client side.
After the button was clicked, some headers are set on the server with PHP to initiate the download.

```
//code snippet:
$filename = basename($datei);

$size = filesize($datei);
$this->response->setHeader('Content-Type', "application/force-download", TRUE);
$this->response->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='.$filename , TRUE);
$this->response->setHeader('Content-Length', $size, TRUE);

return "TEST";   //<--code will never go this far, it is ignored
```

The download works. But I never get something returned as response but the header.
How can I return something e.g. a string, after the download was initiated?

It seems to be impossible to return something to the client after setting the header.

---

**BACKGROUND**

Basically my goal was to show and hide a spinner icon, e.g. show a spinner icon inside the download button while the file is still downloading, and hide it again after it has finished downloading.
Therefor to know if the download has finished, I thought I can just return something from the server to the client, to let the client know it, e.g. "download succeeded".

But im not sure if this would work anyway, maybe the response would arrive before the download has even finished.

Comment: For anyone reading this question, and as confused as I am by the various edits and bad wording:
- to return a string after setting headers, you can. (use "echo" and not "return" in the code and it works). 
- to send both a download file and another string on one go and have JS process it, you can. (Example is a bit too long for comments; there are also caveats).
- to use download headers and also append another string for separate processing in JS, you can't (as chosen answer says). But there are workounds (open in separate window being the obvious one, as mentioned in the answer).

Comment: I always get "This request has no response data available.". I've tried `echo` and `return`, the download is initiated though.

Comment: It will work - the echo is added to the download but will actually screw over what you're trying to do, but it does what you asked. For what you _really_ want to do (i.e. a JS interaction when the download starts or progreses), look at the streaming API for Javascript (I think it's IE10+? supported?) to pull in the file as a datastream AND additional info (how you do this is your call, or you could just branch off as soon as the download starts); and then use saveAs to save the file part of the data. You will still need fallback for other browsers and a bit of playing around to get it to work.

Comment: This may help (not mine): https://codepen.io/davidelrizzo/pen/cxsGb.

Comment: @Robbie this will just take a text from the client and save it on the client?

Comment: It's not going to work as-is - is an example concept you can use and build from there. It demonstrates how to use blobs and save them. So send your blob data (the file to download) using the streaming API, stick it in a blob and call saveas. Meanwhile you have have JS monitor the progress of the streaming API and you can do whatever else you need. Solve the puzzle one bit at a time (e.g. get that codepen working, then do streaming, then do triggers on streaming, then ensure you have fall back) to build the full solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can not**. Don't waste your time trying to look for a hack,  rather design your download page accordingly.

When you tell a browser (using headers) that you are going to provide a file to download like here

```
$this->response->setHeader('Content-Type', "application/force-download", TRUE);
```

Then all fairly recent browsers will follow that advice and download the file, after that they don't care if PHP manages to echo something at the end or not, they don't need it.

Your PHP code is **not being ignored**, it is processing just fine. PHP does not stop you from having any code after you provide some headers for the browser. Its just that once you have told the client that you are going to return a file to download it does not bother what other text you wanted to output. In fact that would be considered part of the download file. You don't see it in your file because its a `return` which is not useful in this content, try an `echo`.

When you provide a Content Type header then you are expected to send the content exactly of that type if you want the browser to successfully understand your server's response.

Look at all the major download sites, almost all of them have their downloads setup so that when you click a download link you are redirected to another page which says *"Your download will begin shortly..."* and meanwhile they initiate another request to their download page which does just that; provides the file to download.

So in one request you can't mix the two together successfully with any fair amount of browser compatibility.

Comment: Basically my goal was to show and hide a spinner icon, e.g. show the spinner icon in the button while the file is downloading, and hide it again after it has finished downloading.

Answer (score 0):

To end the current script you can use `return`, however when used in the top level script (as you have it) it will end execution but **not pass back any return value or output anything as part of the HTTP response**. You need `exit` for this (but see later).

`return` can only pass back a value to calling scripts:

- when used in an include/require, it will end that include/require and pass value back to calling script
- when used in a function, it will end that function and pass value back to calling script

---

To end the current script and output a value as part for the HTTP response, you can use **`exit`** (http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) or `die` (same as exit). But `exit` can change its behaviour when you pass a parameter:

- if a string, it will send as part of the HTTP response
- if an integer, it will use this as an exit code (for command line usage).

---

To output anything to get "returned" as part of the HTTP response, use `echo`. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php). This will output anything that can be converted to a string (i.e. to output an integer or a string) and not change behaviour if an integer or string as `exit` will.

---

The safest option is therefore:

- always use `echo` to send something back as part of the HTTP response
- always use `exit` to end execution;
- use return inside functions or files you know will be "included" (and optionally pass back a return value)

Ideally (to avoid potential ambiguation in the code) for an HTTP response, don't add return values to exit unless you're programming for a command line interface. i.e. for HTTP, use

```
// Outputs something and exists
echo 'TEST';
exit;
```

or

```
// Outputs something and exists
echo 1;
exit;
```

---

If you're outputting a file (and not a variable you have in memory) look at `readfile()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) which will output a file stream to the HTTP response. (Followed by `exit;`)

```
// Outputs a file to HTTP response
readfile('/path/To/My/File/MyFile.txt');
exit;
```

---

*Bonus note: `exit`, `echo` and `return` are not functions, per se, but are language constructs. The return values for `exit` and `return` should not be specified in parenthesis. It'll work, but the PHP manual recommends against it. `echo` can use parameters, and indeed you must if you're passing more than one value to be  output.

Wrong:

- exit('TEST');
- return('TEST');

Correct:

- exit 'TEST';
- return 'TEST';
- echo 'TEST';
- echo ('TEST', 'MORE'),

Comment: I don't really think OP wanted to know that. OP wants to know how to provide a download file and some text output in 1 single http response

Comment: I've directly addressed the question as asked, i.e. why does `return "TEST";` not return anything. OP has, however, changed this question significantly from the first draft - question should be closed and a new one opened if this is not the issue trying to be solved.

Comment: I see, makes sense then. I didn't see the revision history

Comment: Yep - If he'd left the question alone, there is a very simple answer (building on yours - which is equally correct but doesn't provide the full solution). But as this response addresses his question as it currently stands, I'll wait until the OP asks another question with the problem he wants to solve (i.e. in revision 1-3 of his question).

Comment: Of course I asked for the solution for the question as it is right now. The last edit was 2 days ago, the bounty was not even set back then. The edit did not changed the core of the problem. Yes, I want to know how to provide a download file and some text output in 1 single http response, or at least detect on the client if a download was initiated successfully

Comment: Which is not what your questions says. "It seems to be impossible to return something to the client after setting the header." No, it's not impossible (fix your code and the word "TEST" will be sent), but "I want to know how to provide a download file and some text output in 1 single http response" is different and very doable.

Comment: Can I suggest you end the bounty and close / delete this question. Repost the correct question and let me know the link and I'll reply there. Keeps everything cleaner (and you save the bounty!).

Comment: Well, @Hanky Panky understood my question very well, im not sure why you don't? However I already upvoted your answer because it contains useful info.

Answer (score -1):

Well I am using MVC framework and in my controller I have a method that does this and there is no need to re-load the parent page from where download initiated:

```
// Define headers
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
// Read the file
readfile($filePath);
exit;
```

Comment: For me neither, the download works also without reload. But I need to reload for other reasons, directly after the download was initiated.